# Find a function $ \ f(x,y ) \ $ with analytic formula

Tags: functions

Find a  function $ \ f(x,y ) \ $ with analytic formula , whose domain is the **open** triangle with vertices $ (0,0) , \ (1,0) , \ (0,1) \ $ .

**Answer:**

[image]

Let

$ f_1(x,y)=\ln (x) , \\ f_2(x,y)=\ln(y) , \\ f_3(x,y)=\sqrt{1-(x+y)} \ $

Clearly,

the domain of $ f_1 \ $ is $ x>0 \ $ ,

the domain of $ f_2 \ $ is $ \ y>0 \ $ ,

the domain of $ f_3 \ $ is $ x+y<1 \ $

Now if we can combine the above three functions , then we will get the function $ \ f(x,y) \ $

**But I can't combine these.**

**Help me out**

Comment: Did you try $f=f_1+f_2+f_3$ or $f=f_1f_2f_3$? What could the domain be?

Answer (score 1):

There's a fundamental problem with this question.  The domain of a function $f(x,y)$ can be whatever you define it as, as long as the definition works for $(x,y)$ in that domain.  Whether it works for $(x,y)$ outside that domain is irrelevant.  So you could just as well say:

$ f(x,y) = 1$ with domain the open triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.

Comment: In this way how to define $ f(x,y) \ $ to express the region inside a regular Hexagon ? Can you help little more

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you're asking about a function defined **only** on the triangle described, and answer the question under this assumption.

It is relatively straightforward using any function $g(z)$ defined only on $z>0$. An easy example of such a function is $\log(z)$ or $\frac1{\sqrt z}$.

Simply adding these functions of different arguments together yields a function with an intersection of their individual domains. So in your case:

$$f(x, y) = g(x)+g(y)+g(-(x+y))$$

is a correct answer.

In your suggested answer, to combine the functions given, you could just add them together. You do have an error, however: $\sqrt{1-(x+y)}$ is defined on the line $x+y=1$, so you would end up with a non-open triangle.

Feel free to ask for clarification.